Socks5/mtproxy на Ubuntu для телеграм
Всем привет. Стоит задача - поднять на сервере убунту 22.04 socks5/mtproxy, чтобы подключиться к ним через прокси внутри мессенджера телеграм.
Проблема в том, что делаю все по инструкции и после запуска: systemctl start dante-server
Или
systemctl start mtproxy
Все работает и я могу из телеги к ним подключатся. Но, проходит время(бездействие) несколько часов и они выключаются. И чтобы заново к ним подключится нужно заходить на сервер, перезагружать его или заново запускать эти службы
Как сделать, чтобы они не выключались
Socks5 настраивал по этой инструкции(без защиты): https://8host-com.turbopages.org/8host.com/s/blog/kak-nastroit-proksi-server-dante/
Mtproxy настраивал по этой инструкции: https://github.com/HirbodBehnam/MTProtoProxyInstaller
Вывод с сервера:

> root@vps34719:~# sudo netstat -tulnp Active Internet connections (only
> servers) Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address  
> State       PID/Program name tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22           
> 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1014/sshd: /usr/sbi tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38547         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
> 953/containerd tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*       
> LISTEN      961/xrdp-sesman tcp6       0      0 :::22                 
> :::*                    LISTEN      1014/sshd: /usr/sbi tcp6       0  
> 0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN     
> 1017/xrdp udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37306           0.0.0.0:*       
> 1329/docker-proxy udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54054          
> 0.0.0.0:*                           931/avahi-daemon: r udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
> 931/avahi-daemon: r udp6       0      0 :::37306                :::*  
> 1335/docker-proxy udp6       0      0 :::36520                :::*    
> 931/avahi-daemon: r udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*  
> 931/avahi-daemon: r





пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Проблема заключалась в переполнении журнала syslog. Настроил ротацию логов с очисткой каждый час.
И дополнительно добавил в dante.conf параметр перезагрузки каждые 10 секунд. Работает нормально. Иногда долго коннектится, но, думаю, это уже из-за самого хостера сервера.
